# start and stop receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to start and stop a broadcast receiver which detects whether the screen is on or off,and this function should be performed on a button click
,Is there any way to do it.Somebody please help me to find it out.

Comment: This can be done by making a receiver class in activity and by registering/deregistering register on button click

Comment: I had tried calling that but it returns error..Actually the activity is declared inside a device admin receiver,can you  suggest any perfect code for this

Comment: show something before seeking answer